# Divisibility theorem based proof for any square mod 4 being either 0 or 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Kindly help me in understanding the below proof for given statement:

If $n$ is a square, then leaves a remainder $0$ or $1$ when divided by 4.

Proof: The divisibility theorem states that for two integers $a,b$ with $b>0$, then there is a unique pair of integers $q$ and $r$ such that $a =qb +r$ and $0\le r <b$.

Let the number $n= a^2$, for $a$ being an integer. If $b$(divisor)$=4$, then $a = 4q +r$, where $r \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$, so that $n = (4q+r)^2 = 16q^2 + 8qr + r^2$.

If $r=0$, then $n=4(4q^2 +2qr) +0$; if $r=1$, then $n=4(4q^2 +2qr)+1$; if $r=2$, then $n =4(4q^2 +2qr+1) +0$; and if $r =3$, then $n = (4q^2 +2qr+2)+1$. In each case , the remainder is $0$ or $1$.

---

The difficulty lies in the last para. where according to me it should be:

If $r=0$, then $n=4(4q^2 +2qr) +0$; if $r=1$, then $n=4(4q^2 +2qr)+1$; if $r=2$, then $n =4(4q^2 +2qr) +2$; and if $r =3$, then $n = (4q^2 +2qr)+3$.

Comment: If $r=2$, then $n=(4q+2)^2=16q^2+16q+4=4(4q^2+4q+1)+0$.

Comment: Choose $b=2$ and write $a=2b+r$ with $r$ 0 or 1 (even or odd), now square $a$ then bring in 4 and check the remainders of $a^2$ for division by 4.

Comment: @PVanchinathan In fact, the next question (of the book) asks to find a shorter proof by choosing $b =2$. Your answer can be easily elaborated as: $a=2q+r$, and $n = 4q^2 + r^2 + 4qr$, and considering all four cases as follows:   If $r=0$, then $n = 4q(q + r) +0$ (or, simply $4q^2$). If $r=1$, then $n = 4q^2 + 2qr +1$ (or, simply $2q(2q + r) + 1$). If $r=2$, then $n = 4q^2 + 2qr +4$ (or, simply $2(2q^2 + qr +2) + 0$). If $r=3$, then $n = 4q^2 + 2qr +9$ (or, simply $2(2q^2 + qr +4) + 1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the fact that the last $r$ is squared in the expression of $n$.

If $r=2$, then you have $$\begin{align}n=&16q^2+8qr+r^2\\=&16q^2+8q\cdot 2 + 2^2 \\=& 16q^2+16q+4\\=&4(4q^2+4q+1).\end{align}$$

For $r=3$, you missed a $4$ when writing the original solution, so you have

$$\begin{align}n=&16q^2+8qr+r^2\\=&16q^2+8q\cdot 3 + 3^2\\=&16q^2+24q+9\\=&16q^2+24q+8+1\\=&4(4q^2+6q+2)+1\end{align}$$
and since $r=3$, that's the same as $$n=4(4q^2+2qr+2)+1$$

Comment: Thanks, yes I missed it.

Comment: @jiten You know, if this answer (or the other one) is what you need, you should accep it (and upvote any good answer)

Comment: Sorry for that, really missed that too.

Answer (score 1):

Any integer is of the form $2n$ or $2n-1$ (i.e odd or even) 
Now sq. of any number will be in the form $$(2n)^2 =4p or (4n-1)^2 =4q +1$$ 
So we find when that if $n$ is a square, then leaves a remainder $0$ or $1$ when divided by $4$.